# Display custom field filter results on different page

Tags: php, wordpress

On my Wordpress website I am filtering through blogposts via custom fields on 2 seperate places. On the one page I pass the values via querystring and then use query posts to display the filter results on that same page, which works well.

Now, my question is, how do I go about if I want to use the same filters, but display the results on a different page.

The link that passes the querystring:

```
<a href="?location=National">NATIONAL</a>
```

Query posts

```
<?php
       $location = $_GET['location'];
       $catid = $category_link;

        $sps = array(
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'cat' => $catid,
        'order' => DESC,
        'orderby' => date,
        'meta_key' => 'location',
        'meta_value' => $location);
 ?>
```

Display results

```
<?php query_posts($sps); ?>
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

 <li> 
  <?php
      if ( has_post_thumbnail()) 
     {
      echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" class="thumbnail_image_link">';
      the_post_thumbnail();
      echo '</a>';
     }
     ?>
 </li>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>   
    <p>There are currently no results available</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there any way I can modify this code to display on another page?

Comment: Have you tried the `target` attribute of the `a` tag? Like `<a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank">Open google in a new window</a>`

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
<a href="?location=National">NATIONAL</a>
```

lets suppose your page id is 12

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/?page_id=12&&location=National')); ?>">NATIONAL</a>
```

and use same query to retrieve post on this page.....